# How to return elements of Array in reverse order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, reverse

i need to write a method. which will accept any array as input and return another array as output . out put array elements should be in reverse order

```
input a[]={123};
output b[]={321};
```

**note:** as a array and get another array which includes the same elements but in reverse order
**What I tried**

```
public class p112409 
{
   public static int nums[] = { 5, 11, 9 }; 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
     p112409.reverse3(nums); 
} 

public static int[] reverse3(int[] nums) 
{ 
    int rev[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }; 
    int lenght = nums.length; 
    for (int i = lenght - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
      rev[i] = nums[i]; System.out.println(rev[i]); 
    }
    return nums; 
  } 
}
```

lang: Java only

Comment: What have you tried? Might I suggest using a loop to get the last index and putting into an ArrayList?

Comment: Ok, goahead and write.

Comment: whats your effort so far ?

Comment: Do we have commas between 123? Or is it a single number?

Comment: did you tried Collections.reverse(a); ?

Comment: i need basic data structure program. i do not want to use any avail method @SebriZouhaier

Comment: `rev[i] = nums[i];` -- You need a different index for the reverse array starting at 0 and increment it after adding an element. Also you want to `return rev`

Comment: The `Collections.reverse` does not work on primitive datatype arrays... Even with `Arrays.asList`, the output will just be a List<int[]>... :/

Answer (score 1):

The details is in the assignement inside the forloop.

```
public static int[] reverseArray (int[] input){
    int len = input.length;
    int[] output = new int[len];
    for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
        output[i]= input[len-1-i]; // assign from the reverse of the input
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you are changing `rev` and returning `nums` which doesn't make any sense.

Second thing, if the indexes are same then the arrays are also the same.

What I suggest you to do is to use a different index say `k` and iterate from `0` to `length` which would reverse the array.

```
 int rev[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }; 
 int lenght = nums.length; 
 for (int i = lenght - 1, k = 0; i >= 0; i--, k++) 
    {
      rev[k] = nums[i];
    }
 return rev;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Collections.reverse(a);
```

Or implement your proper reverse method

```
private List reverseList(List myList) {
List invertedList = new ArrayList();
for (int i = myList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    invertedList.add(myList.get(i));
}
return invertedList;
}
```

Comment: True, But the OP doesn't want to use any of these in-built functions. _i need basic data structure program. i do not want to use any avail method_

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easiest to create an array with its size defined as the size of the input array, then iterate over a for loop of that same input array length (decrement from a.length to 0).

Put those input array values into the index going the other way in the output array using a counter.

In your case the for loop's first iteration should do this:
b[counter] = a[a.length-1]

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++)
    reversal[reversal.length - 1 - i] = original[i]
```